# Overlay vertical sidebar on top of content

Tags: css, vmware-clarity

How can I overlay vertical sidebar when expanded, rather than pushing content to the right?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-sgfqmc

Comment: Questions seeking help with code should contain [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question itself rather than a link that may stop working in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fixed` position:

```
.clr-vertical-nav {
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
}
```

You will also need to use `margin` on your content to make sure it is not partly covered when menu is closed.

```
.content-area {
   margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to overwrite the layout with some custom CSS:

```
clr-vertical-nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.content-area {
  margin-left: 48px;
}
```